# Show an explicit example concerning Primitive Element Theorem

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

I have a problem,

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, let $L=k(X,Y)$ and $K=k(X^p,Y^p)$. It's evident that $L/K$ is finite and $[ L:K ]=p^2$. Suppose $L/K$ is simple then $L=K(\alpha)$, then $min(K,\alpha)$ must be of degree $p^2$, however $min(K,\alpha)|(x^p-\alpha^p)$, which leads to a contradiction.

So $L/K$ is not simple, we deduce from Primitive Element Theorem that there are infinitely middle fields of $L/K$.

Here comes the part I couldn't solve, show EXPLICIT INFINITELY MANY MIDDLE FIELDS of $L/K$.

I'm stuck because, let $k=F_p$, then if there's no mistaken, there's only finitely many simple extension of $K$, and I coundn't imagine a bigger extension. So help me with this, thank you. show EXPLICIT INFINITELY MANY MIDDLE FIELDS of $L/K$.

Comment: Look at $K[X+cY]$ for $c$ in $k$.

Comment: What if k is finite?

Comment: Good point!  That $K[X+cY]$ for $c$ in $k$ example usually appears with the hypothesis that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Yeah. I kinda prove that there's obly finitely many sinple extension. And I couldn't imagine an extension more complex than simple. That's why i'm stuck

Comment: Calculate the degree of the extensions $K[X+cY]$ and check that if $c \neq 
 c'$ then $K[X+cY] \neq K[X+c'Y]$.  With $k$ algebraically closed you should get your infinitely many intermediate fields.

Comment: @sharding4 $k$ could be $\mathbb F_p$, so your comments do not make sense.